# How to remove <a href link> at javascript print function

Tags: javascript, printing

How to remove  at Javascript print function?
Following is my view page before clicking print button(before fired print function)

[image]

View page after clicking print button (after fired print function)

[image]

I want to remove link(url) from Edit and delete button which are showing below..

**Javascript function**

```
function printDiv(divName)
{
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

Comment: Is there a javascript code on click of the print button?if so can you post it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to add a css class to those and then create a media query for print (if you don't have it already) and hide them.

For example:

```
<a class="hide-for-print">Edit</a>
<a class="hide-for-print">Remove</a>
```

And then in your style file add this:

```
@media print { 
   /* All your print styles go here */
   .hide-for-print { display: none !important; } 
}
```

Of course you can do it by element but you might not want to hide all a tags when printing.

Comment: i have used it....<td><a class="hide-for-print" href="<?php echo site_url('users/edit/')?><?php echo $row->user_id;?>"><button type="button" class="hide-for-print btn btn-success custom_edit">Edit</button></a></td>    and in style  <style>
        /* All your print styles go here */
        @media print {
            /* All your print styles go here */
            .hide-for-print { display: none !important; }
        }
</style>   but its not working

Answer (score 0):

In this way, you will hide the href when you go to print

```
@media print{
    a[href]:after { display:none; }
}
```